# How to make Notification Message Box

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

How to create a notification popup form which closes atomaticaly after finate seconds. To be used as notification message box in the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Put `Timer` to your notification form (drag and drop it from *Toolbox*).
2. Set it's `Interval` to timeout you want form to be shown (in *Properties* window).
3. Subscribe to `Tick` event of timer. In this event handler close form: `this.Close();`
4. Subscribe to `Shown` event of notification form. In this event handler start timer: `timer1.Start();`

Comment: @neo there is not match code to share - most of this steps are done in designer. E.g. dragging `Timer` from toolbox to form, setting interval in properties window, subscribing to events in properties window.

Comment: So simple and so smart!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about Balloons that appear on the bottom-right of your screen? You can use a control called `NotifyIcon`, which then all you'll need to do is edit the `BalloonTipText` and `BalloonTipTitle` properties. You can then display it by calling the method `ShowBalloonTip`.

Sample code:

```
NotifyIcon n = new NotifyIcon();
n.BalloonTipText = "Details of the message go here";
n.BalloonTipTitle = "Message from Program";
n.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
```

If you want to let the user click the icon for whatever purpose, you can subscribe to some events like `BalloonTipClicked`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sergey answer, this is a notification MessageBox I made.

1. Create a new form
2. Add a `Label` and a `Timer` to it.
3. Set `Dock` property of the `label` to `Fill`
4. Set `Enabled` property of the `Timer` to `True`
5. Replace its codes with these (you can change namespace of course)

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   namespace myNotificationBox
   {
      public partial class frmNotification : Form
      {
       private string _message;
       private int _time = 1000;

       public frmNotification(string message)
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           _message = message;
       }

       public frmNotification(string message,int time)
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           _message = message;
           _time = time;
       }

       private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           this.Close();
       }

       private void frmNotification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           lblMessage.Text = _message;
           this.Width = _message.Length*10;
           this.Height = 30;
           tmr.Interval = _time;
           tmr.Start();
       }

       protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnPaint(e);
           ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle,
                                   Color.Teal, 3, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                                   Color.Teal, 3, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                                   Color.Teal, 3, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                                   Color.Teal, 3, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
           //Rectangle rect = this.ClientRectangle;
           //LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Snow, Color.SeaShell, 60); //LightCyan Lavender LightGray
           //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
           //base.OnPaint(e);
       }

       #region Overloaded Show message to display message box.

       /// <summary>
       /// Show method is overloaded which is used to display message
       /// and this is static method so that we don't need to create 
       /// object of this class to call this method.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="messageText"></param>
       /// 

       internal static DialogResult Show(string messageText)
       {
           frmNotification frmNotification = new frmNotification(messageText);
           frmNotification.ShowDialog();
           return frmNotification.DialogResult;
       }

       internal static DialogResult Show(string messageText, int time)
       {
           frmNotification frmNotification = new frmNotification(messageText, time);
           frmNotification.ShowDialog();
           return frmNotification.DialogResult;
       }

       #endregion

   }
   }
   ```
6. Now you can call it in two ways:

   ```
   frmNotification.Show("message"); //default interval would be 1000
   frmNotification.Show("message",2000);
   ```